# How to control treble, bass, volume on Iphone/ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-audio

I need some help/hints on how to control the ipad's volume, how to control the bass and treble  in xcode for an iphone app.

Thanks

Comment: You can't control the iPod music playback's volume or modify the output in any way from your own app.

Comment: Can i control the treble and the bass from my app? I play music from my app, not the ipod music playback

Answer (score 0):

I'd have thought Audio Units would do the job - check the appendix for built-in ones -  the iPod Equalizer should do the job (including volume adjustment within your app - you just can't change the system volume)

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioUnitLoadingGuide_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008781-CH1-SW1